# Is React Context API best replcement and new alternative of Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using **Redux** in the number of my React applications, and it is a good way to use Redux to manage application's state and making the state to be the **"single source of truth"**.

But as in **React 16.3**, the new concept of [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) has introduced which also provides a way to share values/state like Redux Store between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree.

> So, Is React Context API fully replacement or we can say alternative of Redux and will **react-redux**
>   deprecated in the future?

Comment: If you are looking for an easy alternative to Redux, then I would recommend "PullState", its very simple to use. Unlike context API it is a full fledged State Management system like Redux.

Answer (score 1):

Actually [react-redux v6](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases) is now using the new Context API!

redux gives you more features -> the capability of managing reducers, the dispatch function, middlewares, devtools and many more... Moreover `reat-redux` has some useful hidden features, like the capability to not re-render your component if the props of `mapStateToProps` has not changed.

So `redux` + `react-redux` will give your more power than `Context Api`, it depends of your needs.

By the way, it seems like react will progressively integrate `redux` in their api, they added the function `useReducer` in their future [Hook API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) which is really similar to the `redux` api